# Tools for IIS tracing and monitoring

Tags: iis-7.5, trace

I am looking for a tool or tools to trace and monitor IIS processes related to websites and web services.

I use IIS Tracer for this work currently but it isn't perfect or comprehensive.

What other tools would help me?

Comment: Did you try Failed Request Tracing?

Comment: Microsoft has System Center Operation Manager for that

Answer (score 1):

a tool for this is "New Relic" that not only can be used for monitoring web apps in IIS but also used for every web apps based on Ruby, Java, .NET, PHP and Python apps such as Web apps,SQL,..
more info about it is in site: http://newrelic.com